# Dropbox album view with fancybox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox, dropbox

I am trying to include a dropbox-album via fancybox, but the iframe-window doesn't show anything.
Fancybox is already included and working fine with other contents.

jQuery 1.10.1

My href:

```
<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8hnorr9ndb87b98/AABxf73Ubn6R2rsc0SDhUv0Ba" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="various">Dropbox</a>
```

My fancybox js:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '70%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

Thx for any ideas =)

Comment: I tried to resolved. But I get console error as **Refused to display [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8hnorr9ndb87b98/AABxf73Ubn6R2rsc0SDhUv0Ba) in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

Comment: you can't http://jsfiddle.net/9rUBL/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the kind of URL you're using there is a share link to a folder, so it points to a web page that shows the contents of a folder. That web page is on `dropbox.com`, which does not allow framing (for security reasons).

If you had a share link to an individual *file* (like a specific image), you could modify the URL by adding the query string parameter `?raw=1`. This provides a link that redirects to the actual file contents (instead of the web page that contains a preview of the file). But this of course won't work for a folder.